# Categorizing natural content

Tags: php, python, ruby, content-management-system, lexical-analysis

My question is how to extract a relevant category from a natural content.

For example, below is a news article from a newspaper.

> Arsenal have completed the signing of Shkodran Mustafi from Valencia as the Gunners enter deadline day having made six signings this summer, in the form of Lucas Perez, Granit Xhaka, and the young trio of Rob Holding, Takuma Asano and Kelechi Nwakali, alongside the German international. The news comes hours after the north London club announced the transfer of Perez to the Emirates, which is likely to see an end to their transfer business this summer.

I want likely to  categorize this content in category **Sports**. Is there any well written library in any programming languages like python,php,ruby?

Question inspiration : http://www.newsnow.co.uk/

I saw one another question related to this but the answer not satisfying my requirement.

[Auto Categorization of Content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/820296/auto-categorization-of-content)

Comment: monkeylearn is an option

Answer (score 0):

Ther is a rubygem which can help you out in this. check [this](https://github.com/alexandru/stuff-classifier)